# 2 min delays on downloading Azure blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I'm developing an application in C# and use Azure. I noticed, that when I try to load a lot of blobs, some requests take ~2 min. Usually the download time is 1-15 sec.
The strange thing is, that requests can take either 1-15 sec or 2 min (it is never 30 sec, or 1 min etc.). For me it looks like Azure has some kind of throttling or retry mechanism, but I'm not sure.

What causes 2 min delays?
How to avoid such delays?

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = this.GetBlobReference(key);    
using(var msGet = new MemoryStream())
{
    await this._ap.Do(() =>
    {
        var downloadToStreamAsync = blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(msGet);
        return downloadToStreamAsync;
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Can be useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-performance-checklist#subheading16 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/08/02/how-to-monitor-for-storage-account-throttling/

Comment: @Lanorkin thanks for useful links +1

Comment: I've never seen this. Recommend you try same download using azcopy tool and compare results. That should help you isolate whether it is Azure throttling or might possibly be something code related. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is an Azure problem. 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/298

> Currently, there is a short idle timeout on Function apps, so if they don't get requests for 5 minutes the next request causes a cold start which takes longer. We are looking into increasing this timeout, which will make the situation much less common.

And looks like the only one solution is to keep server warm. I think it will be enougth to run a service which will make 1 call to azure storage in 3 mins. To avoid *cold start*

Comment: So, to be clear, this has nothing to do with Azure Storage. This is specific to Web Apps (something you didn't mention using, either in your question or in your tagging).

Comment: It is just theory, I'm not sure for 100%. But it looks similar since symptoms are the same.

Comment: Azure Functions (and Web Apps) are specific to App Services. And the 5-minute timeout for Azure Functions is specific to Azure Functions.